# Why does my click function keeps adding the last class in the css sheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So thanks to some users here, I have some jQuery that allows me to randomly append a class name to my div. I have altered it slightly so that it now works when I click a separate div. The only issue I have now is that when I click it, it will keep appending the random div to my .hexagon div. What I really want it to do is remove it and choose another from the random list. Here is what I have:

```
$(".click").click(function() {
    var randomColors = ["ful","reg","emp"];
    $(".hexagon").each(function(index) {
        var len = randomColors.length;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        $(this).addClass(randomColors[randomNum]);
    });
});
```

so .click adds ful reg or emp to my .hexagon div, but I assume because emp is last in my CSS sheet all my divs end up with that style. I want it to swap them out when I click my button. Can someone help me please?

Here's a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fv6zqu3t/

Comment: Can we please get a jsfiddle w/ HTML and CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the 3 random classes before adding the new random class

```js
$(".click").click(function() {
var randomColors = ["ful","reg","emp"];
$(".hexagon").each(function(index) {
    var len = randomColors.length;
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
    $(this).removeClass(randomColors.join(" ")).addClass(randomColors[randomNum]);
});
});
```

```css
.click {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.click:active {
  background-color: #E8D1D1;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px; 
  height: 28.87px;
  margin: 14.43px 0;
  background-color: #BF7C2A;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 14.43px solid #BF7C2A;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-top: 14.43px solid #BF7C2A;
  width: 0;
}

.ful {
  background-color: #F2B33D;
}

.ful:before {
  border-bottom: 14.43px solid #F2B33D;
}

.ful:after {
  border-top: 14.43px solid #F2B33D;
}

.reg {
  background-color: #BF7C2A;
}

.reg:before {
  border-bottom: 14.43px solid #BF7C2A;
}

.reg:after {
  border-top: 14.43px solid #BF7C2A;
}

.emp {
  background-color: #403221;
}

.emp:before {
  border-bottom: 14.43px solid #403221;
}

.emp:after {
  border-top: 14.43px solid #403221;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="click">RANDOMISE</span>

 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
 <div class="hexagon"></div>
```

`$(this).removeClass(randomColors.join(" "))` this will try and remove any of the classes you have listed in the randomColors array, then you are safe to add your new class.

Your assumption is correct, `emp` is the last class so your styles will show that over the others however it is not the issue

Comment: thank you! I really should learn jQuery. I know what I what I should be doing it's just the syntax in which I do it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the classes before adding, by adding `.removeClass( randomColors.join(' ') )` as shown below:

```js
$(".click").click(function() {
    var randomColors = ["ful","reg","emp"];
    $(".hexagon").removeClass( randomColors.join(' ') ).each(function(index) {
        var len = randomColors.length;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        $(this).addClass(randomColors[randomNum]);
        alert( randomColors[randomNum] );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">Click</div> 
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
```

Comment: No it does not, the OP's code will continuously add classes after each click. OP needs to remove class then add the new random class

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, you want to switch between the tree class values randomly. The jQuery function .addClass() appends class names for the selected elements. So you need to remove old values before setting a new one.

```
$(this).removeClass(randomColors.join(" ")).addClass(randomColors[randomNum]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I can only give one tick but yours works just as well!

Answer (score 0):

you could use **$(this).removeClass();** to remove classes and then add new

```js
$(".click").click(function() {
    var randomColors = ["ful","reg","emp"];
    $(".hexagon").each(function(index) {
        var len = randomColors.length;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("hexagon");
        $(this).addClass(randomColors[randomNum]);
        alert( randomColors[randomNum] );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">Click</div> 
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
<div class="hexagon">Hexagon</div>
```